# How do I fix "Requested resource is in use" when transferring files between Win 10 and Android 12 via USB cable?

Tags: windows-10, backup, android

I'm already using the built in backup but some of these files are things that I really don't want to lose, so I want a 2nd backup storage location.

Trying to backup my photos to a 2nd backup on my NAS but I'm going to put them on my Windows PC first. I connected the phone to the PC, browsed to the DCIM folder, grabbed all the files and dragged to a folder on my Win 10 machine. It copies some things but then says "The requested resource is in use".

The only fix I found online was to disable the Preview Pane. I did that and I'm still getting the error.

I've also tried sending the folder to a shared folder on my NAS via the Files app in Android but it looks like I would have to do them a few hundred at a time. I have an app called DS File that I can share things to but I don't see any way to share a folder, just files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out a few minutes later. Just turning off the preview pane is not enough, you have to turn off any view that might be previewing the files. So "Small Icons" or "Large Icons" or anything like that needs to be off.

Comment: That is because the used protocol MTP is so simple (and stupid) that it only supports one command at a time. For transferring a large set of files activating adb and using adb-sync is mostly the better way.

Answer (score 1):

Thank goodness for this thread.  I just had this problem when trying to copy photos from a digital camera to my laptop hard-disk.
It seemed strange as I have had this camera for 6 years, and never seen this problem before,  I have always simply connect the camera to the laptop, viewd the photo Icons, and dragged off the ones I needed.  But I have not used it fior 3 years, and today I received the "requested resource is in use" message.

MY ANSWER:  I did not have a preview pane. I changed the folder-view for the files on the camera from "large icons"  to "details", and I could copy/drag with no problem.
I then reset folder-view to "large icons"  and I could still drag  without problem,  even when I added new photos to the camera.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @peacheateruk this isn't an answer, it's a comment. Comments should be added with the "Add a comment" link above. Glad it helped you though, it is an annoying problem.